# Add tag info under single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tags, product

I have 1 tag attached to every product under my store. What I want is to show that tag informations under single product page, tag infos like description and title. How do I do that, do I use query and then echo the results or something else.

Comment: Start by looking into the hooks available for you to output the information on the single product page.  https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You may use [`woocommerce_product_meta_end`](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_product_meta_end/) hook to render custom
>   HTML just before product meta, and use [`get_the_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) to get the
>   tag's detail.

Here is a sample code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'wh_renderProductTagDetails');

function wh_renderProductTagDetails()
{
    global $product;
    $tags = get_the_terms($product->get_id(), 'product_tag');
    //print_r($tags);
    if (empty($tags))
        return;
    foreach ($tags as $tag_detail)
    {
        echo '<p> Title: ' . $tag_detail->name . '</p>'; //to print title
        echo '<p> Desc: ' . $tag_detail->description . '</p>'; //to print description
    }
}
```

*Code goes in [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

Hope this helps!

Comment: prefect thanks, just what I needed. Also for those who use Visual Composer you may want to use do_shortcode($tag_detail->description) to format the code.